# Splitting unix output

Tags: unix, grep

I'm trying to extract an address from a file.

```
grep keyword /path/to/file
```

is how I'm finding the line of code I want. The output is something like

```
var=http://address
```

Is there a way I can get only the part directly after the `=` i.e. `http://address` , considering the keyword I'm greping for is both in the `var` and `http://address` parts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
grep keyword /path/to/file | cut -d= -f2-
```

Answer (score 8):

Just pipe to `cut`:

```
grep keyword /path/to/file | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Comment: I needed a list of theme names from a directory with files like this: `theme-xcode.js`, where I just needed the "xcode" bit. This answer helped me. I like to understand, so commenting what I learned: `-f` is the 1-based position of the result of the cut. So, here I get the `xcode.js` from the first cut, and then just `xcode` from the second:
`ls | grep theme | cut -d '-' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f 1`

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the needless pipes:

```
awk -F= '/keyword/{print $2}' /path/to/file
```